# How to print some inputs from user in python?

Tags: python

I am learning python. I tried to the following code but it did not work.
How can I print inputs from a user repeatedly in python?

```
while ( value = input() ):
    print(value)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator which can't be used in `while` loop, it needs a boolean condition

Comment: python is not a C language to assign values to variables in condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignments within loops don't fly in python. Unlike other languages like C/Java, the assignment (`=`) is not an operator with a return value.

You will need something along the lines of:

```
while True:
    value = input()
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

`while true` is an infinite loop, therefore it will always take an input and print the output. `value` stores the value of a user input, and `print` prints that value after. This will always repeat.

```
while True:
    value = input()
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
while 1:
    print(input())
```

If you want to stop taking inputs, use a break with or without condition.